# Appending a 'Blade' into a Container without 'popping-down' existing ones

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am implementing a 'blades' experience in a page.  When I append an additional **Blade** into the **Container**...the previous blades 'pop' down.

- **Q:** How do I append a new element into view without effecting previous elements?

**MY FIDDLE:**
I created a JSFiddle...but the service is not currently available...I will append it shortly.

- https://jsfiddle.net/PrisonerZ3RO/oynae1hd/4/#

**MY CSS:**

```
<style>
    /** DASHBOARD CONTAINER **/
    .dashboard-container { border-right: solid 1px #000; margin-top: 5px; margin-bottom: 5px; overflow-x: scroll; white-space: nowrap; width: 100%; }
    .dashboard-container .widget { clear: both; display: inline-block; vertical-align: top; }

    /** FORM CONTAINER **/
    .form-container { border: 1px solid #ccc; border-radius: 3px; height: 500px; margin-bottom: 5px; padding: 5px; width: 500px; }

    /** BLADE CONTAINER **/
    .blade-container .blade { border: 1px solid #ccc; border-radius: 3px; display: inline-block; height: 506px; margin-right: 2px; padding: 2px; width: 200px; }

</style>
```

**MY HTML:**

```
<script id="tmplBlade" type="text/template">
    <div class="blade">
        Blade
    </div>
</script>

<div class="dashboard-container">
    <div class="widget">
        <div class="form-container">
            Form Controls go here
            &nbsp;&nbsp;
            <input id="btnAppend" type="button" value="Append Blade" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="widget">
        <div class="blade-container">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**MY JAVASCRIPT:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {

    function PageController()
    {
        var that = this,
            dictionary = {
                elements: { btnAppend: null, bladeContainer: null },
                selectors: { btnAppend: '#btnAppend', bladeContainer: '.blade-container', tmplBlade: '#tmplBlade' }
            };

        var initialize = function () {

            // Elements
            dictionary.elements.btnAppend = $(dictionary.selectors.btnAppend);
            dictionary.elements.bladeContainer = $(dictionary.selectors.bladeContainer);

            // Events
            dictionary.elements.btnAppend.on('click', that.on.click.btnAppend);
        };

        this.on = {
            click: {
                btnAppend: function (e) {
                    var html = $(dictionary.selectors.tmplBlade).html().trim();
                    var $element = $(html);

                    $element.hide();
                    dictionary.elements.bladeContainer.prepend($element);

                    // Slide-in
                    $element.show('slide', { direction: 'left' });
                }
            }
        };

        initialize();
    }

    var pageController = new PageController();
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I append a new element into view without effecting previous elements?

I'm not sure if I entirely get what you're asking since you'll always be affecting the other elements by moving them over when you append a new element. You can, however, prevent the pop-down effect you're seeing. The `.ui-effects-wrapper`added by jQuery UI is `display: block`, so add the following to your CSS:

```
.blade-container .ui-effects-wrapper {
   display: inline-block !important;
}
```

Then make sure your other blades are always aligned to the top of your container:

```
.blade-container .blade {
  ...
  ...
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

This will bump all the blades over (right) and allow a new blade to slide in from the left.

Answer (score 2):

I've come across this problem before. The only way I've found to get around it is to do the following:

1) Create a `.hidden` class width `margin-left: -200px`

2) Add a CSS transition on `margin-left` to the `.blade` class

3) Apply the `.hidden` class to a new blade

4) Show the new blade

5) Remove the `.hidden` class from the new blade

Please see the following fork of your fiddle for a working solution: https://jsfiddle.net/yxL4embt/